# Phrase for something that takes a very long time and a lot of resources to understand

Tags: phrase-requests, paraphrasing

I want to paraphrase this sentence into something smaller  - *"Laypersons cannot understand findings from papers in this field, no matter how much time they spend. To understand them, experts are required and the process may require sizeable resources and time"*

I thought of something like *"Findings from these papers are resource-intensive and temporally incomprehensible to laypersons."* but I know it's wrong. What kind of phrase can I use to describe the nature of the process of "understanding findings from papers"?

Comment: *"Understanding these papers requires both the proper background and substantial effort."*

Comment: These papers are complex and challenging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'These papers are **esoteric**' will convey all you require, I believe.

> intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=esoteric&oq=esoteric&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4042j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> Esoteric : Designed for, or appropriate to, an inner circle of advanced or privileged disciples; communicated to, or intelligible by, the initiated exclusively

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64367?redirectedFrom=esoteric#eid)

> An **esoteric** doctoral thesis is not the sort of thing you’d bring up at Thanksgiving dinner. One doesn’t chitchat about prosthetic heart valves in the supermarket checkout line or dive into mathematical representations of braids on a blind date.

[Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/your-ph-d-thesis-sounds-funky-lets-dance-to-it-1510613621)

Comment: @HMK Glad to be of service.

Comment: Oh wow! That is 100% right on target, a great word choice @Nigel J.